# Auto Play Videos (List View)

Tags: android, video, autoplay

How to do an autoplay like facebook in a listview, only one video at a time, and pause it when it comes out of focus.

Below is the code for playing video after OnClick, on Video View in Another Activity, I want it like Facebook that user scrolls and Video plays Automatically.

```
    Videos_URL = intent.getExtras().getString("VideoUrl");

    // Find your VideoView in your video_main.xml layout
    myVideoView = (VideoView) findViewById(R.id.videoview);
    if (mediaControls == null) {
        mediaControls = new MediaController(this);
    }

    // Create a progressbar
    progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
    // Set progressbar title
    progressDialog.setTitle("APPNAME Video ");
    // Set progressbar message
    progressDialog.setMessage("Loading...");

    progressDialog.setCancelable(false);
    // Show progressbar
    // Show progressbar
    progressDialog.show();
    try {
        Uri video = Uri.parse(Videos_URL);
        myVideoView.setVideoURI(video);
        myVideoView.setMediaController(mediaControls);
        myVideoView.start();
```

Is it possible to get Auto Play in Video View in Android??

Comment: You can try using this new library that is recently created and can play vides in listview as you scrool  https://github.com/eneim/Toro

Comment: Thanks. Hope it works, Downloading :)

Comment: Hi there. I'm creator of Toro. Just wondering around and see your question. Please feel free to ask any question about it. Hope it helps your work.

Answer (score 0):

On getview method of adapter you do like this,
it will auto play video when it will come on view.

```
videoView.setVideoPath(videoPath);   
videoView.setOnPreparedListener(new MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onPrepared(final MediaPlayer mp) {
                            //seekbar.
                                 mp.start();
                              } catch (Exception e) {
                          e.printStackTrace();
                  }
```